# Can't solve a step in a specific proof of the "main theorem of algebra"

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I am trying to prove the "main theorem of algebra":

> Let $P(z)=a_0+...+a_nz^n$ be a polynomial of degree $n\ge1$, i.e., $a_n\ne0$, then $\exists w\in\mathbb C$ such that $P(w)=0$.

I am trying to prove this with guidance of an exercise in my lecture notes. The exercise approaches this by contraposition, with the assumption that such a $w$ does not exist. Therefore $\forall w\in\mathbb C:P(w)\ne0$. The function $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb C, f(z)=\frac{1}{P(z)}$ is defined. Next, I am instructed to prove the following statement:

> $\exists R>0$ such that $|z|>R\Rightarrow|z^nf(z)|<\frac{2}{|a_n|}$

I have been struggling with a proof for this statement. I tried $R=1$ and tried to construct $R$ as a function of the coefficients of $P$, but it is all in vain. I was hoping someone could give me a hint as to what to do here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We have some $R$ large enough so that for $|z|>R$, we have $|a_{n}z^{n}|\geq 2(|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}|+..+|a_{0}|)  \geq 2(|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+..+a_{0}|)$(This is saying for high enough absolute values, the dominant term is the leading coefficient term ); then $|P(z)|\geq|a_{n}z^{n}|-|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_{0}|\geq |a_{n}z^{n}|-\frac{1}{2}|a_{n}z^{n}|= \frac{1}{2}|a_{n}z^{n}| \ \forall \ |z|>R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have some questions about it. First, how could your first statement be proven formally? Second, the inequality $|P(z)|\le2|a_nz^n|$ rearranges to $|z^nf(z)|=|\frac{z^n}{P(z)}|\ge\frac{1}{2|a_n|}$ instead of my desired inequality. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the proof. We need a lower bound $|P(z)|$, as you point out.

Comment: To show the first statement rigorously, consider some $R_{1}$ so that for $|z|>R$, we have $|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}|\geq |a_{n-2}z^{n-2}|\geq ..\geq |a_{0}|$. This can always be found because we just need $R_{1}$ to be bigger than $max( \frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n-1}},\frac{a_{n-3}}{a_{n-2}},..,\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}})$. After that, we can choose an $R \geq R_{1}$ large enough so that $|a_{n}z^{n}|\geq 2n|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}|$.

Comment: ^typo, "so that for $|z|>R_{1}$", and "$max( \frac{|a_{n-2}|}{|a_{n-1}|},\frac{|a_{n-3}|}{|a_{n-2}|},..,\frac{|a_{0}|}{|a_{1}|})$"

Comment: I'm in the process of understanding your method. I assume that the fractions of which the maximum is selected are chosen in such a way that fractions with $0$ in the denominator are ommited, but you allow $0$ to be in the numerator. Also, I assume that you take the absolute value of these fractions, because otherwise it doesn't make sense to talk about inequalities of complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, if anywhere some $a_{k}=0, \ 0\leq k<n$, then we simply omit that entry, and consider $|a_{k-1}/a_{k+1}|$ in the list from which you need the 'max'.